# TypeORM returns empty result when using Nestjs

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am suspecting Nestjs is the problem and I am very unhappy about this problem and development.

I have been given an assignment to develop a simple application. I can attest that without the use of Nestjs, everything works perfectly and I didn't have any problem.

Anytime I send a request, The logging from TypeOrm shows the correct SQL query being executed but the result is either null or undefined or an empty array.

I tried it from the SQL console and everything seems to be fine and the result is returned like I expected. I run an application I developed with express.js and everything seems to work perfectly.

My problem is with Nestjs, No result is returned but the correct query is executed.

I don't know how to reproduce the issue with Nestjs because I have to upload the whole repository given the fact it is structured according to Nestjs guidelines.

Comment: we can't tell much without some code. Do some `console.log` on the value that will be returned by some controller's method, at least

Comment: I am feeling completely down and sick because of this problem. However I created a repository because of this and I want to point the most important folders are database, model which contains all entities.

I don't know why this is not working. Somebody please help.

Below is the repository URL https://github.com/volunux/etrs-nestjs

Comment: now tell us the steps to reproduce your issue

Comment: I tried just this morning after you replied, and I ran the program again and it executed successfully, but there was no result even if the SQL query is very correct according to the logger. I